# Powershell Combine two objects on $null

Tags: powershell, object

I want to combine two PowerShell objects. For each $tag1 field that is $null, the equivalent value from $tag2 should be used

```
$tag1=@{'Artist'='Madonna';`
        'Title'='Like a Prayer';`
        'Genre'=$null; }

$tag2=@{'Artist'='Madonna';`
        'Title'='Like a Prayer (single version)';`
        'Genre'='Pop; }
```

The output should be :

```
$output=@{'Artist'='Madonna';`
          'Title'='Like a Prayer';`
          'Genre'='Pop; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input object are [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables):

- Use the `.GetEnumerator()` method to send a hashtable's entries as key-value pairs through the pipeline.
- The [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) allows you to filter in those entries whose value is `$null`.
- The [intrinsic `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) then allows you to update those entries based on the corresponding value in hashtable `$tag2`.

```bash
$tag1.GetEnumerator().
  Where({ $null -eq $_.Value }).
  ForEach({ $tag1[$_.Key] = $tag2[$_.Key] })
```